# silverlight mediaelement RTSP

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, rtsp

As far as I can see silverlight only supports streaming over http even in version 2, as I understand it mms is converted to http and therefore you cannot stream RSTP (I have tried to test this and get network errors unless I stream http).

Does anyone know if RSTP is going to be supported in Silverlight or if it is and how?

Thanks

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are not any plans for RSTP support, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight 3 supports streaming over RTSP through the use of the MediaStreamSource.  Instead of connecting your MediaElement via .Source you use .SetSource and point it at your MediaStreamSource implementation.

The MediaStreamSource is used to allow Silverlight to work with currently unsupported formats such as MP3, MP4, etc.

Be prepared for the usual floundering and lots of internet searching as there isn't a lot of documentation or samples.

Answer (score 0):

As stated there is no native support, but through the MediaStreamSource API you can do just about anything related to protocol and codec.  These guys have an implementation of RTSP in SL.  I had some success with it, but am not actively using it.  http://www.streamcoders.com/